# Jquery Datepicker not rhiding past dates

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquerydatetimepicker

Am using Jquery Datepicker for my project . If i want to change date format my code will be

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

Its not working . But if am using this format its working

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker("setDate", '+1d');
```

Please provide me a solution . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all previous dates, give start date as today date

```
startDate: new Date()
```

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      startDate: new Date(),
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div> Select Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></div>
```

Comment: This is working fine . But other Parameters are not working like  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ 
      startDate: new Date(),
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      setDate : '+1d'
   });

Comment: On this scenario Only startDate working . setDate and dateFormat Not working

Comment: can you please mention exact what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want achieve date format and setdate also with no previous date

Comment: Set Date will be tommorow and from setdate i need to hide all previous date also with DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: check updated snippet you need to add format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',

Comment: TIme format working bro . setDate only not working

Comment: I think for that  You have to initialize the datepicker first: $('#datepicker').datepicker(); only then you can use $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);